# Ruby on rails render file in multiple views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to return the same generic invalid page if a user does not have access to a page. I want to make use of this invalid page from several different views.

How can I render this page without creating them in every view?

Yes, I can create some other controller and redirect to those pages, but I want the url in the browser to be the same as the page the person is trying to access. I want to render the page not redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to create a static page, which we'll call `invalid.html.erb` and place it in your `static_pages` directory (or however you maintain static pages for your app). Make sure you create a route for it in `routes.rb` as well:

```
get 'static_pages/invalid' => 'static_pages#invalid'
```

Then, in your `application_controller.rb` file, you're going to use the rescue_from helper to call a custom method to handle the error:

```
rescue_from User::NotAuthorized, :with => :invalid

def invalid
  redirect_to 'static_pages_invalid_path'
end
```

That's pretty much it. Read more at [Ruby Guides](http://webdev.cas.msu.edu/s12/webapps/bonappetite/devise/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/guides/output/action_controller_overview.html#rescue).